# Fire and forget pattern using BeginNonExecuteQuery()

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, asynchronous

Purpose: 
I'm working on a load test in which I need to keep Sql Server consuming 100% of the CPU all the time.

Method:

- I make an async connection, run BeginNonExecuteQuery() and register a callback. The query is a simple while(1) which keeps the cpu busy and never returns.

Problem:

- There are times when the sql command is interrupted and the callback is invoked. In such cases I need to retry the sql command. In the callback I do the following:

  ```
          try
          {
               // If execution is incomplete, cancel the sqlCommand
               if (!result.IsCompleted)
               {
                  command.Cancel();
               }
               command.EndExecuteNonQuery(result);
           }
           catch(SqlException ex)
           {}
           finally
           {
               // if connection closed, reopen
               // retry sql command anyway
           }
  ```

Is this the cleanest way to do so? I read that Cancel() doesn't apply to async commands. And that EndExecuteNonQuery() blocks till the command finishes execution, which in my case seems to be true from my runs. Also, does the retry logic make sense?

- Along the same lines, I'd like to voluntarily cancel the async command midway after a timeout. Would calling 
  `command.Cancel(); EndNonExecuteQuery();` 
  work? Or will that invoke the callback again?

Answer (score 1):

The main examples of `Cancel` seem to be with **reader**-based queries. I don't know if it is designed for use with the async pattern.

If it doesn't work, I suspect the only supported way of doing what you want here would be with a command-timeout - so timeout after (say) 30 seconds and re-issue it if desired. Oddly enough, I doubt the designers took to long considering use-cases like "I need to keep the CPU at 100% and never exit"...

Comment: I thought of that but msdn says command timeouts are ignored during async method calls: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout.aspx

Comment: @Panther interesting. Then `Cancel()` looks like your main tool. Does it really not work here?

Comment: I don't think it is. I get an exception asking me to enable MARS, which i presume is happening when I invoke it again in the finally block if the connection is still open. I'll play around with it a bit more to see what's going on.

Comment: @Panther re "if the connection is still open" - more accurately, "if there is still an active command on the connection"

Comment: correct, should've worded it better.I was describing what I was doing in the finally block: `if(connection.state==ConnectionState.Open) command.BeginExecuteNonQuery();`